# Should the tag [united-kingdom] be removed, and replaced with its 4 countries?

Tags: discussion

https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-kingdom contains the warning:

> Note that the UK does not have a common legal system across its jurisdictions - consider using [scotland] or [england-and-wales] or [northern-ireland].

Yet many posts with this tag still neglect this distinction, and answerers must ask the questioner or express their confusion about [the intended jurisdiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_geography_of_the_United_Kingdom#Overview_of_administration).

Wouldn't removing it teach posters  and spur them to choose jurisdictions? From [Tom Bolam](https://www.fladgate.com/lawyer/tom-bolam/), Senior Associate (as of 1-29-2018), Fladgate (Solicitors' firm):

> [United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland (to give it its full name) has three separate and distinct legal systems: (i) Scotland; (ii) England and Wales; and (iii) Northern Ireland.](https://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=8f9476e8-b712-4726-b675-21463a3355e9)

Answer (score 9):

There are some questions that are unique to a particular country, but many issues in academia are UK wide and others are EU wide. I wouldn't replace the tag, but it might make sense to create a Wales tag if there are enough Welsh specific questions. That said, it seems you want the tags to make a statement and that probably is not a valid reason.

Comment: So, Tldr: keep UK, add subregions when needed.